# Derivation of expected improvement for Bayesian Optimization.

Tags: probability

Given that $$I(x) = f_{t+1}(x) - f(x^+)$$ and $f_{t+1}$ follows a Gaussian distribution characterized by $\mu(x), \sigma^2(x)$,, how to show that

\begin{align*}
        & E(I(X)) \\
        &= \displaystyle{\int_{I=0}^{I=\infty} I \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma(x)}} \exp{(-\frac{(\mu(x)-f(x^+) - I)^2}{2\sigma^2(x)}})dI} \\
        &= \sigma(x) [\frac{\mu(x) - f(x^+)}{\sigma(x)} \Phi(\frac{\mu(x)-f(x^+)}{\sigma(x)}) + \phi(\frac{\mu(x) - f(x^+)}{\sigma(x)})]?
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $x^+=\text{argmax}_{i<t+1}f(x_i)$. You can evaluate the integral by substitution: try $u=(\mu(x)-f(x^+)-I)/\sigma(x)$ s.t. $I = \mu(x)-f(x^+)-\sigma(x)u$ and change the lower limit accordingly. This gives 3 separate integrals of that can be expressed in terms of the pdf and cdf of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, which sum to the expression above.